# jQuery can't get trigger working

Tags: jquery, triggers

I've set this simple example up but for the life of me I cant work out why it's not working.

```
jQuery(function() {
$("#otherbutton").click(function () {
  $("#firstbutton").trigger('click');
  }) 
});
```

Live Example http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/mlsBf

Comment: Your example doesn't show that code at all...

Comment: and the code in your code pen doesn't even have any html elements with either of the ids used in your jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work normally using `.on`, tested on jQuery 1.9.1.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gUfxU/)**

```
$(function () {
 $('#otherbutton').on('click', function () {
  $('#firstbutton').trigger('click');
 });
 $('#firstbutton').on('click', function () {
  $(this).text('clicked!');
 });
});
```